# Saturation block

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue with the answer given in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/how-to-draw-saturation-symbol-inside-a-node-in-tikz/65475?noredirect=1#comment368432_65475).

As suggested in the comments to its answer, I modified the solution as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcounter{image}
\setcounter{image}{0}

\tikzstyle{square} = [draw, rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered]

\tikzset{drawinside/.code args={#1}{
        \draw($(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.east)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
        \draw($(#1.south)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
        \draw($(#1.south west)!0.4!(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.south west)!0.165!(#1.west)!0.5!(#1.center)$)--(#1.center);
        \draw(#1.center)--($(#1.north east)!0.165!(#1.east)!0.65!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north east)!0.45!(#1.east)!0.45!(#1.center)$);            
   }
}

\tikzset{record/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        rectangle,draw,minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2
    }
}

\newcommand{\drawrecord}[1]
{
\stepcounter{image}
{
\node [record=1 cm and 1 cm, name=a\theimage] at {#1};
}
\node[drawinside={a\theimage}]{};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\drawrecord{0,0};

\node (sq) [square] {};
\drawrecord{sq};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I keep receiving a `! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.` error when I call `\drawrecord`

. how may I solve this issue?

. Is there a way to define `\drawrecord` as a `\tikzstyle` instead of a new command?

**EDIT:**

for the second question, I have been suggested to look into "append after command", but I cannot find documentation about it, anyone has a link?

**EDIT2:**
actually, the second question is kind of redundant, I can simply call

```
\node [record=1 cm and 1 cm, name=newnode, right of=oldnode];
\node[drawinside={newnode}]{};
```

in my document.
And

```
\tikzset{drawinside/.code args={#1}{
    \draw($(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.east)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
    \draw($(#1.south)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
    \draw($(#1.south west)!0.4!(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.south west)!0.165!(#1.west)!0.5!(#1.center)$)--(#1.center);
    \draw(#1.center)--($(#1.north east)!0.165!(#1.east)!0.5!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north east)!0.4!(#1.east)!0.3!(#1.center)$);            
}
}
```

is symmetrical (the previous one is slightly off)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to define a `newshape`, instead of using [Claudio's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65475/1952), use [Percusse's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65479/1952).

Next code slightly modifies `satnode` shape defined by Percusse. I've changed its name to `record` and some dimensions to look more like your example.

You can use

```
\node[record,minimum size=1cm,fill=blue!30,draw] (a) {};
```

to place a `record` where you want, fix it's size, color, ... and also use its anchors for later use.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclareshape{record}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
\inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
\inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]
\foreach \x in {center,north east,north west,north,south,south east,south west}{
\inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x}
}
\foregroundpath{
\pgfpointdiff{\northeast}{\southwest}
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0.33\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{-0.33\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.33\pgf@xa}{0}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{0}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[record,minimum size=1cm,fill=blue!30,draw] (a) {};
\node[record,draw,fill=red!30,minimum height=12mm, minimum width=6mm] (a2) at (-1,1.5) {};
\node[record,thick,draw=purple!30,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1.5 cm,fill=yellow!10, above right=.5cm and .4cm of a] (a1){};
\draw[-latex] (a2) -| (a);
\draw[-latex] (a) -| (a1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way of doing things, this time with the `path picture`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  saturation block/.style={%
    draw, 
    path picture={
      % Get the width and height of the path picture node
      \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}%
        {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
      \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
      % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
      % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
      \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
      %
      % Draw annotation
      \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1); 
      \draw (-1,-.7) -- (-.7,-.7) -- (.7,.7) -- (1,.7);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [saturation block, minimum size=0.5cm] at (0,0) {};
\node [saturation block, minimum size=1cm] at (0,1) {};
\node [saturation block, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] at (0,2.25) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great answer, is it possible to set a default minimum size in the macro?

Comment: You can add the properties `minimum width = x mm, minimum height = x mm,` inside `saturation block/.style={ ... }`

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax problem here:

```
\node [record=1 cm and 1 cm, name=a\theimage] at {#1};
```

`at` expects a coordinate, so you need

```
\node [record=1 cm and 1 cm, name=a\theimage] at (#1) {};
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newcounter{image}
\setcounter{image}{0}

\tikzset{
square/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw=black,
  minimum width=1cm,
  minimum height=1cm,
  text centered
  },
drawinside/.code args={#1}{
        \draw($(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.east)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
        \draw($(#1.south)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north)!0.3!(#1.center)$);
        \draw($(#1.south west)!0.4!(#1.west)!0.3!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.south west)!0.165!(#1.west)!0.5!(#1.center)$)--(#1.center);
        \draw(#1.center)--($(#1.north east)!0.165!(#1.east)!0.65!(#1.center)$)--($(#1.north east)!0.45!(#1.east)!0.45!(#1.center)$);            
   },
record/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        rectangle,draw,minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2
  }
}

\newcommand{\drawrecord}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{image}%
  \node [record=1 cm and 1 cm, name=a\theimage] at (#1) {};
  \node[drawinside={a\theimage}]{};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawrecord{0,0};
\node (sq) [square] {};
\drawrecord{sq}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! :)
any idea about the second part of the question?

Comment: @Federico I am not sure about your second question. What should the style do?

Comment: the same as `drawrecord`, but as a style and not a command, so to be able to write `\node[drawrecord, left of =oldnode]{}` instead of `\node(new)[left of=oldnode]{};\drawrecord{new};` The arrows from/to the block would also look better.

Comment: @Federico If I understand correctly, I am afraid what you are after is a new shape, not just a style. This, of course, can be done, but it is rather a long process. Perhaps someone else will help you with that.