# Tikz place drawing at a certain node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

The following figure stands for a saturation block in a block diagram:

[image]

The idea is to use this figure as a node at different positions in drawings and place it relatively to other nodes. Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,shapes.arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
,auto
,>=latex'
,block/.style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex, align=center, draw,
               fill=black!10, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm}
,input/.style={coordinate}
,output/.style={coordinate}
]
    \def\saturationBlock#1#2{\node [block] (#1) [#2] {};
        \begin{scope}[scale=0.4,shift={(3.75,0)}]
            \draw[thick]    (  -1,   0) -- (   1,   0);
            \draw[thick]    (   0,  -1) -- (   0,   1);
            \draw[thick]    (  -1,-0.9) -- (-0.5,-0.9)  -- ( 0.5, 0.9) -- (   1, 0.9);
        \end{scope}
    }
    \draw node [input]          (input)                                 {};
    \saturationBlock{saturation}{right = of input};
    \draw node [output]         (output)    [right = of saturation]     {};
    \path
    (input)                     edge[->]    (saturation)
    (saturation)                edge[->]    (output)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

leading to the result:

[image]

If the shift command (`shift={(3.75,0)}`) is omitted, the figure looks like this:

[image]

Obviously the drawing of the saturation sign is not referred to the location of the node (`\saturationBlock`). What is the proper proceeding to place the drawing at the origin of the corresponding node?

Comment: related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/how-to-draw-saturation-symbol-inside-a-node-in-tikz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I think that [percusse's `satnode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65479/1952) is a better solution, here you have an alternative `saturation` style which already draws the whole block with a `path picture` command. Something similar could be done with a `pic` but `node` placement is easier.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten <>/.style={shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
    saturation/.style={
        minimum size=10mm, 
        draw,
        fill=black!10,
        path picture={
            \draw[thick,shorten <>] (path picture bounding box.west)
                                  --(path picture bounding box.east);
            \draw[thick,shorten <>] (path picture bounding box.south)
                                  --(path picture bounding box.north);
            \draw[thick] ([shift=(45:2mm)]path picture bounding box.south west) 
                           --++(0:2mm)--(path picture bounding box.center);
            \draw[thick] ([shift=(225:2mm)]path picture bounding box.north east) 
                           --++(180:2mm)--(path picture bounding box.center);
        },
    }]

    \node[saturation] (a) {};
    \draw[<-] (a.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw[->] (a.east)--++(0:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: another really nice solution indeed. even more elegant for the type of drawings i fulfill.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have problem with defining coordinates for your `saturationBlock`. Lines inside it should be tied with it, not have absolute coordinate. See, if the following solution work for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,shapes.arrows}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
,auto
,>=latex'
,shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm}% <--- new
,block/.style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex, align=center, draw,
               fill=black!10, rectangle, minimum height=10mm, minimum width=10mm}
,input/.style={coordinate}
,output/.style={coordinate}
                    ]
\def\saturationBlock#1#2{\node[block] (#1) [#2] {};
    \draw[thick,shorten <>]    (#1.west)  -- (#1.east) ;% <--- modified 
    \draw[thick,shorten <>]    (#1.north) -- (#1.south);% <--- modified
    \coordinate[above right=2mm of #1.south west] (#1sw);% <--- new
    \coordinate[below left =2mm of #1.north east] (#1ne);% <--- new
    \draw[thick]    (#1sw) -- + (+0.2,0)  -- (#1.center) % <--- modified
                    (#1ne) -- + (-0.2,0)  -- (#1.center);% <--- modified
                        }
\draw node [input]          (input)                                 {};
\saturationBlock{saturation}{right = of input};
\draw node [output]         (output)    [right = of saturation]     {};
\path[->]   (input) edge (saturation)
            (saturation) edge (output);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Probably more elegant solution you obtain with small pictures `\pic`, which is designed for similar small figures.

[image]

Comment: exactly, what I was looking for!