# Switching and saturation blocks in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate this image because of its very poor quality:
[image]

I started with the example block diagram [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/) but I have no idea how to copy the style of the saturation block (which is similar to the one described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65469/how-to-draw-saturation-symbol-inside-a-node-in-tikz/65475?noredirect=1#comment368432_65475) but much more complex) and the A/M switches.

A helping hand would be very welcome!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Controller};
    \node [block, right of=controller, node distance=3cm] (system) {System};
    % We draw an edge between the controller and system block to 
    % calculate the coordinate u. We need it to place the measurement block. 
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (system);
    \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
    \node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y$}(output);
    \draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
    node [near end] {$y_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to define new building blocks for you scheme: for `sum` and separation and write in existed block your text. on the way as are positioning try to add missing block, on the star simple rectangles which can later replaced with correct symbols. btw, example is pretty old with obsolete syntax ...

Comment: HI ! do you have take a lot on  `circuitikz` ? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz